# Creating left-to-right sliding presentation

Tags: presentations

I found [this](http://cr.yp.to/talks/2008.09.15/slides-twopage.pdf) presentation document by D. J. Bernstein. Is it possible to create it in `latex`?

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Perhaps. But it is too ugly to live...

Comment: Use geometry or standalone to create a really wide page, then pack lots of minipages side by side.

Comment: TBH, it looks a lot like it was made with my old TeXPower package :-)

Comment: It must be possible.  The pdf info says it was made with pdfTeX.  Maybe ask djb how he did it!

Comment: @Mark This could be the last option (DJB may not be of that type, I've heard).... :-)

Answer (score 1):

An **`animate`** based solution for AR (see second code box for `animate`-free solution, as requested in the OP):

[image]

The slide-show is built from an existing PDF (here, one of the example files shipping with **`beamer`** is used; it should **not** contain overlays) by means of a master source file (shown below) and pdfLaTeX.

The slide-show pauses on every full slide, but can be paused everywhere and resumed in both directions.

The master file (`animate` version):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% adjust this %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\myslides{beamerexample-conference-talk.pdf}
\def\TransSteps{50} % number of transition steps
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{animate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{intcalc} %modulo computation with \intcalcMod
\usepackage{media9} %for buttons
\def\PdfXimage#1#2{\pdfximage page #1 {#2}} %PDF page into XObject

% store all slides in XObjects and reference these pairwise in parent boxes
\savebox{0}{\PdfXimage{1}{\myslides}\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}
\edef\XObj{\the\pdflastximage}
\edef\slidewd{\number\wd0 sp}\edef\slideht{\number\ht0 sp}
\edef\numSlides{\the\pdflastximagepages}
\multido{\i=2+1,\iPair=1+1}{\numexpr\numSlides-1\relax}{
  \PdfXimage{\i}{\myslides}
  \savebox{0}{\rule{0pt}{\slideht}\makebox[\slidewd][l]{\pdfrefximage\XObj}%
    \makebox[\slidewd][l]{\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}}
  \edef\XObj{\the\pdflastximage}
  \pdfxform 0
  \expandafter\xdef\csname pair\iPair\endcsname{\the\pdflastxform}
}

% write timeline file
\newwrite\TimeLineFile
\immediate\openout\TimeLineFile=slideshow.txt
\multido{\i=0+1}{\numexpr(\numSlides-1)*\TransSteps+1\relax}{
  \ifthenelse{\intcalcMod{\i}{\TransSteps}=0}{
    \immediate\write\TimeLineFile{*::\i} %pause on every full slide
  }{
    \immediate\write\TimeLineFile{::\i}
  }
}
\immediate\closeout\TimeLineFile

% button
\def\buttonface#1{% width
  \tikz[x=#1,y=#1,transparency group]{%
    \useasboundingbox (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
    \shade [ball color=gray,opacity=0.6] (0,0) circle (0.4);
    \fill [color=white,opacity=0.6] %triangle
      (-0.152,0.224)--(-0.152,-0.224)--+(30:0.4844)--cycle;
  }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\def\iPair{1}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{%
  \begin{animateinline}[label=slideshow, timeline=slideshow.txt, nomouse]{25}
  \whiledo{\iPair<\numSlides}{%
    \multiframe{\numexpr\TransSteps\relax}{%
      dOffset=0pt+\dimexpr\slidewd/\TransSteps\relax%
    }{%
      \makebox[\slidewd][l]{%
        \hspace{-\dOffset}\rule{0pt}{\slideht}%
        \expandafter\pdfrefxform\csname pair\iPair\endcsname}%
    }%
    \xdef\iPair{\the\numexpr\iPair+1\relax}%
    \newframe%
    \ifnum\iPair=\numSlides% last slide
      \makebox[\slidewd][l]{%
        \hspace{-\slidewd}\rule{0pt}{\slideht}%
        \expandafter\pdfrefxform\csname pair\the\numexpr\iPair-1\endcsname}%
    \fi%
  }
  \end{animateinline}%
}}%
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\makebox[\slidewd][l]{%
    \mediabutton[
      jsaction={
        if(anim.slideshow.isPlaying)anim.slideshow.pause();
        else anim.slideshow.playBwd();
      }
    ]{\reflectbox{\buttonface{0.8cm}}}%
  \hfill%
  \mediabutton[
      jsaction={
        if(anim.slideshow.isPlaying)anim.slideshow.pause();
        else anim.slideshow.playFwd();
      }
    ]{\buttonface{0.8cm}}%
}}
\end{document}
```

The master file (`animate`-free version):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% adjust this %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\myslides{beamerexample-conference-talk.pdf}
\def\TransSteps{50} % number of transition steps
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\usepackage[pdfstartview=Fit]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{intcalc} %modulo computation with \intcalcMod
\def\PdfXimage#1#2{\pdfximage page #1 {#2}} %PDF page into XObject

% store all slides in XObjects and reference these pairwise in parent boxes
\savebox{0}{\PdfXimage{1}{\myslides}\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}
\edef\XObj{\the\pdflastximage}
\edef\slidewd{\number\wd0 sp}\edef\slideht{\number\ht0 sp}
\edef\numSlides{\the\pdflastximagepages}
\multido{\i=2+1,\iPair=1+1}{\numexpr\numSlides-1\relax}{
  \PdfXimage{\i}{\myslides}
  \savebox{0}{\rule{0pt}{\slideht}\makebox[\slidewd][l]{\pdfrefximage\XObj}%
    \makebox[\slidewd][l]{\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}}
  \edef\XObj{\the\pdflastximage}
  \pdfxform 0
  \expandafter\xdef\csname pair\iPair\endcsname{\the\pdflastxform}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\def\iPair{1}%
\whiledo{\iPair<\numSlides}{%
  \def\iStep{0}%
  \whiledo{\iStep<\TransSteps}{
    \xdef\dOffset{\the\dimexpr\slidewd*\iStep/\TransSteps\relax}%
    \begin{preview}%
      \makebox[\slidewd][l]{%
        \hspace{-\dOffset}\rule{0pt}{\slideht}%
        \expandafter\pdfrefxform\csname pair\iPair\endcsname}%
    \end{preview}%
    \edef\iStep{\the\numexpr\iStep+1\relax}
  }%
  \xdef\iPair{\the\numexpr\iPair+1\relax}%
  \newpage%
  \ifnum\iPair=\numSlides%
    \begin{preview}%
      \makebox[\slidewd][l]{%
        \hspace{-\slidewd}\rule{0pt}{\slideht}%
        \expandafter\pdfrefxform\csname pair\the\numexpr\iPair-1\endcsname}%
    \end{preview}%
  \fi%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Inkscape with the Sozi Plugin to create the sliding effect. TexText or the default Inkscape LaTeX rendering plugin can give you the math/text.

I'll try to update my response with an example later.

Comment: It is not clear :-(. Your example may help.

Answer (score 0):

The same question popped up in [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8816726) thread on HN and someone suggested that it could be easily done using [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As is, your answer is more a comment. Could you please make it more complete and really answer the problem directly, including the necessary code?